# How to efficiently generate ordered list from couple of lines with Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext2

How to efficiently generate ordered list from couple of lines?

Let's say:

```
list item 1
list item 2
list item 3
```

into:

```
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**Notes:**

I could deduct the `select_lines` from [documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/editing/editing.html#column-selection), the problem was:

- on Win (Win 8) `Ctrl+Alt+arrow` was used for desktop rotation (? :/)
- on Mac (OS X 10.7.5) `Ctrl+Shift+arrow` was used by Mission Control 
  to animate desktop, despite that the Shortcuts setting shows only `Ctrl+Up/Down` without `Shift`. After un-checking the option it works as supposed to.

Comment: You could easily disable mission control as well as desktop rotation or switch keybindings to other ones if you don't want.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac, can be used on windows as well with a bit of changing the shortcuts.

1. Put the cursor before the first character of the first line.
2. Hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> and press <kbd>arrow down</kbd> 2 times, this will create 3 cursors at each line.
3. Holding <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> press <kbd>arrow right</kbd> to go to the end of the lines while selecting, this will select each line separately.
4. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to wrap with tags and immediately start typing `li`. It will type on both tags at the same time - on the opener and the closing tag
5. Press <kbd>esc</kbd> to cancel multiple selections.
6. Now select as you normally would the whole list including one line above and one line below the list.
7. Repeat the step 4., but type `ul`.

Now all keybinding are default Mac bindings, on Windows/Linux you may find your bindings in the key bindings config. Just for reference I will write down all that were used so you could find them easier:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+w"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "name": "Packages/XML/long-tag.sublime-snippet" } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+down"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} },
```

The <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrow right</kbd> is the same as pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>end</kbd> on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Alternative for steps 1-3: Highlight all lines, `Split into Lines` (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>)

Comment: @thgaskell Great one!